# install npm truffle -p getting many deprecation warnings when I am traying to run this code

Tags: npm-install, truffle

Some of the deprecated warnings are as follows:

> npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@6.2.6: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
> npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
> npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

These are keeping to show other deprecation warnings. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: There's nothing to solve. These tools or versions of tools have been listed by their authors as deprecated. The only way to make the warnings go away is to stop using those libraries or versions of libraries. If you're using a library that depends on these deprecated tools, you should contact the author to see if they can upgrade their dependencies.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.